# the number of different least positive residues modu $p^2$ of $x^{p-1}$ is $= p+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Conjectures:

> Let $n$ be postive integers, Prove or disprove there exist infinitely many prime numbers $p$,such  the number of different  least positive residues modu $p^2$ of $x^{p-1}$ is  $= p+1$?

I don't know if the question is correct. Feel this problem using Fermat's little theorem.

I know if $(x,p)=1$,we have $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$,if $(x,p)>1$,then 
$x^{p-1}\pmod p$  the residues  have the same value.

Comment: Hint: Simply expand $x$ as $ap+b$, and discard all terms with $p^2$.

Comment: It's true for $every$ prime..... For odd prime  $p$  the set $G(p,2)=\{n: 1\le n<p^2\land p\not |\,n\}$ with multiplication mod $p^2$ is a $cyclic$ group with $\phi(p^2)=p(p-1)$ members. So mod $p^2$ the set $\{n^{p-1}:n\in G(p,2)\}$ has $p$ members,  none divisible by $p$, while $(py)^{p-1}\equiv p^2 \mod p^2. $ Giving, in all , $p+1$ residues.... And the property also holds for $p=2$.